# Как переместить курсор мыши?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

В Visual c++ создаём оконное приложение, в нем Баттон. Нужно событие клик на Баттон, и чтоб запускалась функция SetCurcorPos(); нажал на Баттон, мышь переместилась на указанные координаты в скобках функции. Это для простоты вопроса. И так главное, как запихать в Баттон SetCursorPos(); ?

Comment: Простите, возможно я не правильно понял. _Оконное приложение_ - это что именно? В заголовке было  WinForms, значит C++/CLI. Верно? Если не прав, напишите, я откачу правку и удалю ответ.

Comment: Windows forms c++

Comment: WinForms - это библиотека платформы .NET. Код под неё пишется на _управляемых_ языках: C#, VB.NET, C++/CLI и других. Так что у вас не C++, а C++/CLI - это _разные_ языки. Если вам нужен именно C++, тогда вы выбрали не тот GUI-фреймворк.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Используем свойство [Cursor.Position](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position?view=netframework-4.8)

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    Cursor->Position = Point(300, 300);
}
```